# Is Thread.interrupt() evil?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

A teammate made the following claim:

> "`Thread.interrupt()` is inherently broken, and should (almost) never be used".

I am trying to understand why this is the case.

Is it a known best practice never to use `Thread.interrupt()`? Can you provide evidence why it is broken / buggy, and should not be used for writing robust multithreaded code?

**Note** - I am not interested in this question if it's "pretty" from a design preservative. My question is - is it buggy?

Comment: Are you sure they meant 'buggy' when they said broken? Perhaps they meant "encourages bad behavior / hard-to-maintain code", which I would say is the case.

Comment: When people make claims like that, always ask them for a technical explanation of *why* it's broken. It's possible that your teammate is thinking of `Thread.stop()`. It's also possible that he/she is simply repeating someone else's dogma without giving it any thought.

Comment: It *is* pretty and not buggy. Your team mate has probably confused `interrupt` with `stop` and `suspend`. The `interrupt` method is used throughout the `java.util.concurrent` package, and your tasks won't be cancellable if they don't support it.

Comment: Very short version of my answer below: I think you could replace "Thread.interrupt" and "broken" with "multithreaded code" and "really very hard to do right" and your teammate would be a little closer to reality....  ;-) (although erickson's comment is more to the point than my snark).

Comment: Maybe your mate were talking about stop or suspend? See this: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: helios - definitely not, he was talking about interrupt. And he knows a ton about threading, so can't easily dismiss his opinion, but I also can't find references to why he believes interrupt is evil.

Comment: Again, ask *him* to explain himself. He's making a claim that others don't agree with, so ask *him* to provide the references. And if he can't give you a reason, then it doesn't matter how much he *appears* to know.

Comment: He said he'll come over and write an answer when he gets a free 30 minutes :)

Comment: Thread.interrupt() had such a good start in life, a loving home, caring parents, no one saw the evil coming...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Short version:**

> Is it a known best practice never to
>   use Thread.interrupt()?

No.

> Can you provide
>   evidence why it is broken / buggie,
>   and should not be used for writing
>   robust multithreaded code?

The opposite is true: it is critical for multithreaded code.

See Listing 7.7 in [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/listings.html) for an example.

**Longer version:**

Around here, we use this method in one specific place: handling `InterruptedExceptions`.  That may seem a little strange but here's what it looks like in code:

```
try {
    // Some code that might throw an InterruptedException.  
    // Using sleep as an example
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    System.err.println("Interrupted in our long run.  Stopping.");
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

This does two things for us:

1. It avoids eating the interrupt exception.  IDE auto-exception handlers always provide you with something like `ie.printStackTrace();` and a jaunty "TODO: Something useful needs to go here!" comment.
2. It restores the interrupt status without forcing a checked exception on this method.  If the method signature that you're implementing does not have a `throws InterruptedException` clause, this is your other option for propagating that interrupted status.

A commenter suggested that I should be using an unchecked exception "to force the thread to die."  This is assuming that I have prior knowledge that killing the thread abruptly is the proper thing to do.  I don't.

To quote Brian Goetz from JCIP on the page before the listing cited above:

> A task should not assume anything about the interruption policy of its
>   executing thread unless it is explicitly designed to run within a
>   service that has a specific interruption policy.

For example, imagine that I did this:

```
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    System.err.println("Interrupted in our long run.  Stopping.");
    // The following is very rude.
    throw new RuntimeException("I think the thread should die immediately", ie);
}
```

I would be declaring that, regardless of other obligations of the rest of the call stack and associated state, this thread needs to die right now.  I would be trying to sneak past all the other catch blocks and state clean-up code to get straight to thread death.  Worse, I would have consumed the thread's interrupted status.  Upstream logic would now have to deconstruct my exception to try to puzzle out whether there was a program logic error or whether I'm trying to hide a checked exception inside an obscuring wrapper.

For example, here's what everyone else on the team would immediately have to do:

```
try {
    callBobsCode();
} catch (RuntimeException e) { // Because Bob is a jerk
    if (e.getCause() instanceOf InterruptedException) {
        // Man, what is that guy's problem?
        interruptCleanlyAndPreserveState();
        // Restoring the interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

The interrupted state is more important than any specific `InterruptException`.  For a specific example why, see the javadoc for [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29):

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.

As you can see, more than one InterruptedException could get created and handled as interrupt requests are processed but only if that interrupt status is preserved.

Comment: The sleep() only gets interrupted if someone interrupts it; in your handler, you just demote the checked exception into an unchecked one.  Ouch.

Comment: @Will, that's the point: I accept the interrupt and then force the interrupt to continue.  If I simply had a "throws InterruptedException" clause on the method, anyone with a "catch (Exception e) {}" block would eat the exception.  Sleep gets interrupted on a control-C: if you eat the exception, your thread won't stop.

Comment: @erickson, Thanks - I added the link to the listing just now.  I never realized that they'd put the code samples up on the JCIP site.  That should come in very handy!

Comment: I would argue that your code snippet still eats the exception. If the code is called from some other method, which then goes on to perform a  long-running operation, the thread won't finish. It's only ok to do what you suggest if `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` is basically at the *end* of a `Runnable`'s `run` method. If the code could be called from anywhere, it should throw an unchecked exception to force the thread to die.

Comment: @artbristol, I changed the language to emphasize the importance of the interrupt status.  Also discussed how throwing an unchecked exception is worse than useless.

Comment: @BobCross finally blocks will still run; synchronized locks will be dropped; your 'jerk' comment is noted and my downvote stays

Comment: @artbristol, your opinion is noted - you're arguing with Brian Goetz, not me.  Ref: JCIP Chap 7.1 page 143.

Comment: @BobCross without the book in front of my I can't check, but you might be misinterpreting. I'm saying you need to preserve the interrupt status - always - but that you should probably *also* throw an exception, because otherwise the calling code is going to merrily carry on (unless it happens to check the interrupted status, and when did you ever do that, except as part of a thread pool implementation?).

Comment: @artbristol I agree with Bob; however, I also support your idea that it is preferable, if possible, to throw InterruptedException too. Personal opinion, I think it is less likely to introduce bugs by throwing an exception and makes the intent clearer. But your argument that "the calling code is going to merrily carry on" I think does not hold water because if the caller itself is a long running task, it *should* be checking the interrupt status. Otherwise you are saying that does not manage its own cancellation policy, which is risky.

Comment: @ChadNB But calling code doesn't necessarily *know* it's in a long-running task; it could be any old library, invoking a callback, or it could be some framework.

Comment: @ChadNB, you are right: the long running tasks should be checking their interrupt status.  If my code is being called by their code, I may not have the option of throwing the exception: if I can't change my method signature, for example.  However, I can pass the message up of "we've received an interrupt signal: you, the calling code, should really figure out how to exit cleanly."  See Listing 7.7 (and the surrounding text) in JCIP for related discussion.

Answer (score 16):

The only way I'm aware of in which `Thread.interrupt()` is broken is that it doesn't actually do what it seems like it might - it can only actually *interrupt* code that listens for it.

However, used properly, it seems to me like a good built-in mechanism for task management and cancellation.

I recommend [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) for more reading on the proper and safe use of it.

Answer (score 12):

The main problem with `Thread.interrupt()` is that most programmers don't know about the hidden pitfalls and use it in the wrong way. For example, when you handle the interrupt, there are methods which *clear* the flag (so the status gets lost).

Also, the call will not always interrupt the thread right away. For example, when it hangs in some system routine, nothing will happen. In fact, if the thread doesn't check the flag and never calls a Java method which throws `InterruptException`, then interrupting it will have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not buggy. It actually is the basis of how you stop threads in Java. It's used in the Executor framework from java.util.concurrent - see the implementation of `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.Sync.innerCancel`.

As for failure, I've never seen it fail, and I've used it extensively.

Comment: Exactly. It's very important that code checks for interruption if you intend to use it in a cancellable task. There's nothing "evil" about `interrupt`; it is still depended on heavily by experts like Doug Lea.

Answer (score 3):

One reason not mentioned is that the interrupt signal can be lost which makes invoking the Thread.interrupt() method meaningless. So unless your code in the Thread.run() method is spinning in a while loop the outcome of calling Thread.interrupt() is uncertain.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that when in thread `ONE` I execute `DriverManager.getConnection()` when there is no database connection available (say server is down thus finally this line throws `SQLException`) and from the thread `TWO` I explicitely call `ONE.interrupt()`, then both `ONE.interrupted()` and `ONE.isInterrupted()` return `false` even if placed as the first line in the `catch{}` block where `SQLException` is handled.

Of course I workarounded this issue implementing the extra semaphore but it is quite troublesome, as it is the very first such issue in my 15 years Java development.

I suppose it's because of bug in `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`. And I investigated more to confirm that the call to the `native` function consumes this interruption in all cases it trhows its own, but preserves it when succeeded.

Tomek

P.S. I found the [analogous issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5223).

P.P.S
I enclose a very short example of what I'm writting above. The registered class can be found in `sqljdbc42.jar`. I found this bug in classes built on 2015-08-20 then I updated to the newest version available (from 2017-01-12) and the bug still exists.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TEST implements Runnable{
    static{
        try{
//register the proper driver
           Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("Cannot load JDBC driver (not found in CLASSPATH).");
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
//prints true
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx\\xxxx;databaseName=xxxx;integratedSecurity=true");
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
//prints false
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        (new Thread(new TEST())).start();
    }
}
```

If you pass something completely incorrect, as `"foo"`, to the `DriverManager.getConnection()`, you will obtain the message "No suitable driver found for foo", and the second printout will be still true as one would expect. But if you pass the correctly built string but, say, your server is down or you lost your net connection (that can generally occurr in the production environment), you will see the `java.net` socket timeout error printout and the thread's `interrupted()` state is LOST.

Answer (score -3):

THe problem is not that the implementation is not buggy but rather your thread is in an unknown state when it gets interrupted and this can lead to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Interrupting is graceful signalling, its not pausing or aborting the thread.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake.  Stop is the evil one.  Thanks!