# Understanding thread interruption in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading thread interrupting from [this](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-thread-interruption-in-java) article. It says following:

> > Before a blocking code throws an `InterruptedException`, it marks the interruption status as false. Thus, when handling of the `InterruptedException` is done, you should also preserve the interruption status by `callingThread.currentThread().interrupt()`.
>
> Let’s see how this information applies to the example below. In the task that is submitted to the `ExecutorService`, the `printNumbers()` method is called twice. When the task is interrupted by a call `toshutdownNow()`, the first call to the method finishes early and then the execution reaches the second call. The interruption is called by the main thread only once. The interruption is communicated to the second execution of the `printNumber()` method by the call to `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` during the first execution. Hence the second execution also finishes early just after printing the first number. Not preserving the interruption status would have caused the second execution of the method to run fully for 9 seconds.
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
>     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
>     Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {
>         printNumbers(); // first call
>         printNumbers(); // second call
>     });
>     Thread.sleep(3_000);                                     
>     executor.shutdownNow();  // will interrupt the task
>     executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
> }
> private static void printNumbers() {
>     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>         System.out.print(i);
>         try {
>             Thread.sleep(1_000);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // preserve interruption status
>             break;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I tried running above code and it prints:

```
01230
```

When I comment `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` from `catch` block, it prints:

```
01230123456789
```

Though I feel I understand explanation before code, I dont think I understand why the explanation is correct, partly because I did not find any related explanation / sentence in the official doc. Here are my specific doubts:

1. Does that mean we need every method call in `Runnable` submitted to `ExecutorService.submit()` to have catch `InterruptedException` and call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in it for whole `Runnable` body to interrpt? If we miss to catch `InterruptedException` and call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in any method call in `Runnable`, then it will not be interrupted?
2. If above is correct, why there is not such explanation in the [doc of `Thread.interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())?
3. Is it like if we want to do any closure task on interruption in any method, then only we should catch `InterruptedException`, perform any task to be done and then call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`?
4. If answer to question 3 is yes, then when we should be doing closure task? I feel any closure task should be done before `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, but in the given example, `break` is called after `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.
5. After thinking on question 4 a bit more, I feel I dont understand it clearly how thread interruption is handled. Earlier I felt interrupted thread simply gets killed immediately, but that does not seem to be the case. How thread interruption occurs? Is there any oracle official link explaining the same?

Comment: It is an incredibly common misconception that one should re-interrupt a thread after catching an `InterruptedException`. There is no need to do so. There's no point--you're the one who's handling the flag. Who else is going to notice that the flag is set aside from  yourself? Answer: Nobody. I'll try to post an answer later if nobody else does.

Comment: I didnt find anyone saying that (no need to re-interrupt a thread after catching an `InterruptedException`) and that too is an important question (questions 1 and 3). In fact [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021133/6357916) seem to suggest re-interrupting in `catch()` block. But I dont get why? Does catching `InterruptedException`  clears interrupted status of the thread?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest misconception with thread interruption is that this works out of the box. Yes, the basic mechanics to set the interrupt flag of a thread are made available to deal with thread interruption, but how a thread should do this is still up to the developer. See the note on ExecutorService `shutdownNow` method:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt, so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

For example:

```java
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
      printNumbers(); // first call
      printNumbers(); // second call
    });
    executor.shutdownNow(); // will interrupt the task
    executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private static void printNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.print(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Although the executor was shutdown and the thread was interrupted, it prints:

```
01234567890123456789
```

This is because there is no thread interruption handling whatsoever.

If you would for example test if the thread was interrupted using `Thread.interrupted()`, then you can actually deal with an interruption within your thread.

To halt after the first `printNumbers` you can do:

```java
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
      printNumbers(); // first call

      // this checks the interrupt flag of the thread, which was set to
      // true by calling 'executor.shutdownNow()'
      if (Thread.interrupted())
        throw new RuntimeException("My thread got interrupted");

      printNumbers(); // second call
    });
    executor.shutdownNow(); // will interrupt the task
    executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private static void printNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.print(i);
    }
  }
}
```

This wil execute the first `printNumbers` and print:

```
0123456789
```

The problem with your example is that whenever you catch `InterruptedException`, the interrupt flag of the thread is reset to `false`.

Therefore, if you would execute:

```java
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
      printNumbers(); // first call
      printNumbers(); // second call
    });
    Thread.sleep(3_000);
    executor.shutdownNow(); // will interrupt the task
    executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private static void printNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.print(i);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1_000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // the interrupt flag is reset, but do not do anything else
        // except break from this loop
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This wil interrupt the first call to `printNumbers`, but due to the catch of `InterruptedException`, the thread is not considered interrupted anymore and therefore the second execution of `printNumbers` will continue and the `sleep` is never interrupted anymore. The output will be:

```
0120123456789
```

However, when you manually set back the interrupt flag after the catch, during the second execution of `printNumbers` the `sleep` is interrupted due to the interrupt flag being true and you immediately break out of the loop:

```java
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
      printNumbers(); // first call
      printNumbers(); // second call
    });
    Thread.sleep(3_000);
    executor.shutdownNow(); // will interrupt the task
    executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private static void printNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.print(i);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1_000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // the interrupt flag is reset to false, so manually set it back to true
        // and then break from this loop
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It prints `012` from the first `printNumbers` execution and `0` from the second `printNumbers` execution:

```
0120
```

But remember, this is only because you are manually implementing thread interruption handling, in this case due to using `Thread.sleep`. As shown by this last example:

```java
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
      printNumbers(); // first call
      printNumbersNotInterruptible(); // second call
    });
    Thread.sleep(3_000);
    executor.shutdownNow(); // will interrupt the task
    executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private static void printNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.print(i);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1_000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  private static void printNumbersNotInterruptible() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.print(i);
    }
  }
}
```

This will print out:

```
0120123456789
```

This is because `printNumbersNotInterruptible` does not deal with thread interruption and therefore completes its full execution.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you. It's exactly what I was looking for and it shows exactly how interruptions work in all the important cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thread interruption is not something that kills a thread right away. It is a suggestion for the thread to end themself.

1. The code in your thread will not terminate automatically. So your code should react to thread interuption by terminating gracefully. One good practice is to reset the interrupted flag everytime it was consumed, by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`. Following operations that respect the status will throw InterruptedException, and will not just continue.
2. 
3. `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` should be the first statement in the catch block, to make sure any cleanup doesnt block again. (Using finally for cleanup is also a good idea)
4. In that specific case I would have pulled the try / catch out of the for loop.
5. It is basically a suggestion for the thread to end itself.

> [Java language specification 17.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.3)
>
> Interruption actions occur upon invocation of Thread.interrupt, as well as methods defined to invoke it in turn, such as ThreadGroup.interrupt.
>
> Let t be the thread invoking u.interrupt, for some thread u, where t and u may be the same. This action causes u's interruption status to be set to true.
>
> Additionally, if there exists some object m whose wait set contains u, then u is removed from m's wait set. This enables u to resume in a wait action, in which case this wait will, after re-locking m's monitor, throw InterruptedException.
>
> Invocations of Thread.isInterrupted can determine a thread's interruption status. The static method Thread.interrupted may be invoked by a thread to observe and clear its own interruption status.

-

> [Oracle Tutorial about interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)
>
> The Interrupt Status Flag
>   The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as the interrupt status. Invoking Thread.interrupt sets this flag. When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static isInterrupted method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag.
>
> **By convention, any method that exits by throwing an InterruptedException clears interrupt status when it does so.** However, it's always possible that interrupt status will immediately be set again, by another thread invoking interrupt.

Comment: There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020992/is-thread-interrupt-evil

Comment: What do you mean by "One good practice is to reset the interrupted flag everytime it was consumed"? Do you mean catching `InterruptedException` clears thread's interrupted status so we need to again call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in the catch block?

Comment: @anir yes thats what i meant, i changed my answer to make that clearer. Thats the reason your version without it printed all 10 numbers in the second run. The `sleep()` was not interrupted again.

Comment: But then why `InterruptedException` [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) dont say catching this exception clears thread's interrupted status?

Comment: @anir It actually does, see the comment in the code example from the doc.
`The following code can be used to achieve this effect:
  if (Thread.interrupted())  // Clears interrupted status!
      throw new InterruptedException();`

Comment: Yeah...but that comment is for `Thread.interrupted()`, and [doc of `Thread.interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) also states that explicitly. The comment is not for `InterruptedException`.

Comment: @anir because throwing or catching `InterruptedException` doesn't directly affect the interrupted status. There is just a convention to clear the status before your throw the exception. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: That link has a sentence saying "By convention, any method that exits by throwing an InterruptedException clears interrupt status when it does so." What it does mean by "by convention"? Does it mean, if a method throws `InterruptedException` (without catching it), java runtime will automatically clear its interrupted status? If yes, then arent here we are catching the exception (instead of throwing)?

Comment: `by convention` means that nothing really enforces it. All methods in the standard library will behave that way, but others might not. catching/throwing/instaniating `InterruptedExveption` will not affect the interrupted status. If you want to throw it, you should follow the convention by clearing the status (code example is in the javadoc of `InterruptedException`).